# Erorr when calculating periodReturn in R

Tags: r, return, quantmod

I have a csv. file with daily ohlc data for fx-rates. Now I need the hourly data but I get an error message when I try using the periodReturn function of the quantmod package.
Here is what I did:

```
EURUSD_Min = CSV_EUR


eurusd_minutedata_df = as.data.frame(EURUSD_Min)


colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[1] <- "Date"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[2] <- "Time"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[3] <- "Bid"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[4] <- "Ask"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[5] <- "High"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[6] <- "Low"
colnames(eurusd_minutedata_df)[7] <- "Close"

eurusd_minutedata_df$Date = as.POSIXct(paste(eurusd_minutedata_df$Date, eurusd_minutedata_df$Time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
eurusd_minutedata_df_final <- eurusd_minutedata_df[-2]



  index_min_eurusd <- eurusd_minutedata_df_final$Date
  data_min_eurusd <- data.frame(eurusd_minutedata_df_final[,2:6])
  df.ohlc.min_eurusd_xts <- xts(data_min_eurusd, index_min_eurusd)
  eurusd_min_return <- diff(log(Cl(df.ohlc.min_eurusd_xts)), lag=1)
 
  eurusd_min_return

 2021-07-28 21:16:00  1.690188e-04
 2021-07-28 21:17:00  3.379520e-04
 2021-07-28 21:18:00  0.000000e+00
 2021-07-28 21:19:00 -1.689617e-04

 periodReturn(eurusd_min_return, period = "hourly")
```

But I get the error:

```
   Error in if (on == "secs" || on == "mins") on <- substr(on, 1L, 3L) : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to make it work?

The original data looks like this:
# A tibble: 2,982 x 7

```
     `Local Date` `Local Time`    Bid   Ask  High   Low  Open
       <date>       <time>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1 2021-07-30   23:00         1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19
    2 2021-07-30   22:59         1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19
    3 2021-07-30   22:58         1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19
    4 2021-07-30   22:57         1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19
    5 2021-07-30   22:56         1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19  1.19
```

Comment: Dear Nina, can you provide some data sample?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to examine the intermediate results. The format specification for your `as.POSIXct` call has seconds but your data does not. So you get an NA at the very start of your processing. Here's a demonstration of my claim.

```
 txt <- "2021-07-30 23:00" # my guess at the results of `paste` on your data
 as.POSIXct(txt, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#[1] NA
```

You should be printing out intermediate results to find out where NA's are being generated. (This may not be the only place, but it surely would have given you an NA, so you *could* try changing your format spec appropriately.)

```
 as.POSIXct(txt, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#[1] "2021-07-30 23:00:00 PDT"
```

I suspect that you have not actually given an unambiguous description if the data being processed since the error didn't occur until later in your processing. Better would be to offer the results of `dput(head(eurusd_minutedata_df))` as the starting point and then give all the needed `library` calls to load needed packages, and then the code that produces that error.